# Changing where passenger looks for RubyGems

Tags: macos, passenger

I've installed the Passenger Preference Pane on OSX but whenever I try to run an app I get a 500 Internal Error.  Looking at the log gives me the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:25:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:25
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/bin/passenger-spawn-server:53:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/bin/passenger-spawn-server:53
[ pid=403 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:725 time=2009-11-15 23:33:38.110 ]:
  Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/Users/waynemolina/Projects/sandbox/rack-hello-world': The spawn server has exited unexpectedly.
  Backtrace:
     in 'virtual boost::shared_ptr Passenger::ApplicationPoolServer::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (ApplicationPoolServer.h:471)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:521)
```

Since rubygems works everywhere else, I can only assume this error is because Passenger is looking in the wrong place for Rubygems.  I installed Rubygems manually and it's located in `/usr/local/bin/gem` according to `which gem`.  However, `whereis gem` returns `/usr/bin/gem` instead.  I'm more than a little confused on what steps I need to take to fix this short of just reinstalling OSX and upgrading the built-in RubyGems install instead of installing it myself.

Comment: please post your passenger configuration from apache.

Comment: More of a server or Mac OS question -- try: http://serverfault.com